# Django - Wrong date format on template

Tags: python, django

I have a small problem but cannot figure out why. On my django shell:

```
In [2]: Post.objects.dates('created', 'month')
Out[2]: [datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)]
```

but on my template,

```
{% for d in dates %}                        
  <li><a href="#">{{ d|date:"m Y"}}</a></li>                        
{% endfor %}
```

which gives "04 2012" instead of "05 2012". Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Time zone difference. The date is midnight on 5/1/2012, so if your server is behind GMT, it's only 4/30/2012.

Comment: just to add some more clarification: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/
enable timezone support for your project so that way you can adjust output to the user's TZ using template filters: {% load tz %}{{ value|localtime }}